# Error when sending REST command to Bluemix with Android

Tags: android, rest, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am using Bluemix and Cloudant. The IDE is android studio 2.2.
I want to send a REST command to the server and am getting this error:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://[myUserId].cloudant.com:443/text`

I also tried `https://[api key, api secret]@[myUserId].cloudand.com:443/text`, but got the same error. I checked and I have read-write permissions.
When I click the link at the android monitor, it seems to work.

I am using the POST method, and also tried to put the Authorization in the header.

Comment: which httpclient and or httpurlconnection is being used as your client? if HUConn then get the inputStream for the ERROR and process the IS to list the actual error msg from the server. If u dont use HUrlConn then figure out how to dump WIRE & HEADERS for that particular client.  FileNotFound... is not the errMsg  being received via the low level protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your connectivity with 'curl' from the command-line e.g.

```
curl 'https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/'
```

It should return some JSON to you and would verify that

- you have connectivity
- your Cloudant service is up
- your credentials are correct

In notice your example says 'cloudand.com' not 'cloudant.com', but I assume that is just a typo ;).

If you are developing a Java application, then you may want to consider the [Cloudant Java library](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant) which is built just for this purpose.

Comment: now i totally confused :)
i wanted to use the library for that, and it's working great.
but the pepole at IBM told me that it's not good idea to talk directly to the server, and i have to use RESTful only.
the library even faster then REST command.
by your humble opinion, should i use the library, rather then the REST?

Comment: The library certainly makes your life easier - it is simply making HTTP calls for you but has some wrapper functions that hide some of the complexity. If you're happy making HTTP requests yourself in Java, then that's fine too.